Dataplex is recreating the Default bigquery table
I have deleted the default bigquery table that is created with the dataplex zone from the entities tab. But dataplex is recreating the same table again with the same name .
How to stop table recreation of deleted tables
2024-08-15 15:41:19.931 CEST Successfully performed delete table operation for table projects/******/datasets/*****/tables/table1 corresponding to entity ***** in zone ******
 
2024-08-16 00:05:44.785 CEST Successfully performed create table operation for table projects/******/datasets/*****/tables/table1 corresponding  to entity ***** in zone ******​


Hi @Ramkrishna, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.

@SouravDutta , Issue created link
